# returning a constant reference

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am studying C++ now. I am trying to study it from [***this link***](http://newdata.box.sk/bx/c/index.htm). Here in the 10th chapter, when I study about operator overloading, in an example program "*this" is returned as a constant reference. [***Here it is***](http://newdata.box.sk/bx/c/htm/ch10.htm#Heading38)

Here in this program we are dereferencing the current object using "*this" and returning the value means the current Counter object as constant reference.

So when I do like this:

```
Counter a = ++i;
```

is the current object assigned to a constant reference and the value of the constant reference is copied to the new object created using default copy constructor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
Counter a = ++i;
```

You're simply copying from the `const Counter &` being returned from the function. What you're doing is equivalent to (from the point of view of `a`):

```
const Counter & ref = ++i;
Counter a = ref;
```

As long as you define `a` to be a `Counter` object, it will be created as a brand new `Counter` object (Or you will get a compiler error if the copy-constructor is not accessible).

Comment: To add to the answer, `T t = x;` is known as **Copy Initialization**,  It tries to convert `x` to an object of type `T`. (It then may copy over that object into the to-initialized object, so a copy constructor is needed)

Comment: @Als thanks for generalising the answer, but I'm not sure if it's entirely correct. Doesn't `T t = x;` simply call the constructor of `T` with an input argument of type `X`? (or `const X` , `X &` etc...)

Comment: @Als Ah, I see, your comment is what happens if there's no `T` constructor from `X`, but `X` is convertible to `T`.

Comment: This is what I think. As seeing this many answers, will anybody give me a final answer? I created a copy constructor Counter::Counter(const Counter & cp) { cout << "Copy constructor" << endl;}. This is being called when a = ++i, but as the values are not copied properly it is showing values as 24564 or something. Hence the copy constructor is being called that is sure.

Comment: @kaushik "is the current object assigned to a constant reference?" - no, "the value of the constant reference is copied to the new object" - almost yes, the value of what the reference refers to is copied to `a`. (or your custom copy constructor is called, which doesn't necessarily copy anything unless you make it do that.)

Comment: @kaushik the bottom line is when you say `Counter a`, you're defining a new `Counter` object which will be stored on the stack. Since C++ is a statically typed language, no matter what assignment you do afterwards, you can not change the fact that `a` is a brand new `Counter` object living on the stack. It can't, after a statement, suddenly start being a reference.

Answer (score 0):

well, actually this class has a operator++ functions that works for both ++var or var++.

```
26:    const Counter& Counter::operator++()
27:    {
28:       ++itsVal;
29:       return *this;
30:    }
```

And since i is an object we can do this assignment for sure.
So in this case, as we can see here:

```
Counter a = ++i;
```

We`re just assigning an incremented-object to another of the same type (Counter).

Did that answer your question? If not, i`m sorry, i think i didn`t get your problem.

Comment: FYI, postfix and prefix increment have can have two different implementations entirely. Postfix is implemented using `operator++(int)`, prefix using `operator++()`

Comment: It isn't really assignment, but copy construction with the "=" syntax. Assignment would be if `a` was declared previously and then assigned the value of incremented `i`.

Answer (score 0):

The case you mention is really straightforward.

```
Counter a = ++i;
```

will be translated to the same as...

```
++i;
Counter a = i;
```

References et.c. are not involved at all...

Comment: In this particular example, a reference is involved in the copy constructor of `Counter`.